# SQLite3 order by field

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
c.execute("SELECT WPNumber, ROUTE, WPID FROM rte WHERE ROUTE = ? AND (WPID = ? OR WPID = ?) LIMIT 3", (x[1], x[0], x[2])))
```

The query works, but I need it to return the result of WPID = x[0] first. In other words, if x[0] is further down the table, it still has to be returned as the first result.

I have fiddled around a bit and I think order by field would do the job. However, my SQL knowledge is limited and I cannot get the query to work. Am I on the right track? And what would the query look like?

Comment: Do you mean that VALUE of WPID is same as X[0] should in at top of the ResultSet ?

Comment: Yes, WPID = x[0]. It always has to be returned as the first result, regardless of its position in the table.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `ORDER BY`, you need to convert the two ID values into something that is guaranteed to be smaller for the first ID.
In the general case, this is possible with a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
c.execute("SELECT WPNumber, ROUTE, WPID" +
          " FROM rte" +
          " WHERE ROUTE = ? AND WPID IN (?, ?)" +
          " ORDER BY CASE WPID WHEN ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END" +
          " LIMIT 3",
          (x[1], x[0], x[2], x[0]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:

`c.execute("SELECT WPNumber, ROUTE, WPID FROM rte WHERE ROUTE = ? AND (WPID = ? OR WPID = ?) ORDER BY " + X[0] + " LIMIT 3 ", (x[1], x[0], x[2])))`

Order by Clause with Order sequense at last
e.g.

`SELECT WPNumber, ROUTE, WPID FROM rte WHERE ROUTE = "foo" AND (WPID = 11 OR WPID = 22) ORDER BY 11, 22 LIMIT 3`

Comment: "SELECT WPNumber, ROUTE, WPID FROM rte WHERE ROUTE = ? AND (WPID = ? OR WPID = ?) LIMIT 3 ORDER BY" + x[0], (x[1], x[0], x[2])))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ORDER": syntax error

Comment: Even if you rearranged the `ORDER BY` clause so that it is in the correct position, numbers in `ORDER BY` are interpreted as result set column numbers.

Comment: I don't know which technology you used but you should write the query as i have mentions in order by clause.

Comment: ("SELECT WPNumber, ROUTE, WPID FROM rte WHERE ROUTE = ? AND (WPID = ? OR WPID = ?) LIMIT 3 ORDER BY " + x[0], (x[1], x[0], x[2]))) gives me: "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: WAYPOINT1"

Comment: Can you update your query should be like this:

Your Query should be like this in
`SELECT * FROM rte WHERE ROUTE = "Your ROUTE" AND (WPID = CAST(123 AS INTEGER) OR WPID = CAST(456 AS INTEGER) )
ORDER BY 
LIMIT 3`

`Limit` should be after `Order by` clause